# get distance in meters maxscript

Tags: distance, units-of-measurement, maxscript

Is there a way to get distance between two objects in meters?

I'm trying this right now

```
        units.displayType =#metric
        myDistance = distance aObject1 aObject2

        label1.text = distance  as string
```

Of course this is giving me the distance between those objects but in units of 3dsmax...

So if anyone knows a way or a formula i will be really grateful thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole topic in maxscript help dedicated to this, [Units Struct - Accessing System and Display Units](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/index.html?url=files/GUID-DB50F450-C3D1-47A5-98A2-A3460171003-1997.htm,topicNumber=d28e671230)

The piece of code you need would look like this:

```
label1.text = units.formatValue myDistance
```

Comment: oh wow thank you yeah i found some topics but the help on that is not clear(at least to me) thank you very much