# Maxscript: How can I change the format of vertex locations from generic units to meters?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

Thanks for taking the time to look at this question.

I am trying to change the output of vertex positions from generic units to meters. I found the following code (slightly modified) from a different SO question. It correctly outputs vertex positions in generic units. How can I make it output in meters?

```
VertDataFile = createfile ((GetDir #export)+"/Vertex Position Data 20.txt")

for i in geometry where classof i == Editable_Poly do
(
for j = 1 to (polyop.getNumVerts i) do format "%" (" \n " +  (polyop.getVert i j node:i as string)) to:VertDataFile
format "\n" to:VertDataFile
)
```

I found a SO question similar to mine, but I couldn't make much sense out of it. [get distance in meters maxscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269434/get-distance-in-meters-maxscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was setting my unit type to meters in the preferences of 3DS Max. 
Also, under Customize -> Units Setup -> System Unit Setup -> 1 Unit = 1.0 needs to be set to "Meters." Further, 3DS Max needs to be reset (soft reset) and then the geometry needs to be re-imported. Next, the file must adopt the current setting that was just applied. Do not re-adopt the files scale or this will all mess up again.